# PHP tasks for database

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables in the Database.
One contains a list of Inventories with name, creation date and ID.
The second table contains individual products, and one column here contains IDs from the Inventory List table.

I write all inventories from the inventory list to the Frontend. There is a detail button next to each listed inventory and after clicking it I need to list all the products with the corresponding inventory ID.
But somehow I can't figure out what to use for it?
Could you please advise me what such a query should contain?

Comment: You would need to use a JOIN query, where you can link the common identifiers between each database, likely with your ID column. Can you post sample data from both tables?

Comment: Your going to have to include a lot more detail on what are trying to do. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question . At the very least we'll need some info about your database structure, some sample data, and the expected output.